# What is the right way to create this type of piecewise function on LaTeX?

Tags: tables, math-mode

[image]

I've seen other solutions but they look rather bold, and messy, and very big. I want something like this, so I can use the code as a template.

Comment: search for `cases` environment on this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
g(x)=\begin{cases}
          x \quad &\text{if} \, x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
          -x \quad &\text{if} \, x \notin \mathbb{Q} \\
     \end{cases}
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I usually write `\text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$}`

Answer (score 5):

Please observe variants of position of `x` and `-x`. The second and third are suggested ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
-x&\text{if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
\]
or
\[
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}x&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
-x&\text{if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
\]
or
\[
g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
x&\text{if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$}\\
-x&\text{if  $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$}
\end{array}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]